# Generate a list of possible subset from a set in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, poker, probability-theory

I'm working on a computing probabilities of winning in a poker (texas hold'em) game. And for that I have to make a function that returns every combination of 5 cards possible from the two cards of the hand and the 3 or 4 or 5 cards on the table. 
I thought about doing a match on the number of cards on the table. So if I have 3, then the only set of five cards is the two in hand + the 3 on the table, but once I have 4 or 5 cards on my table I will be having from 6 to 21 combinations possible so I started this way

```
let compute_comb (d:donne) (t:table) =
  let l = listTable t in
  let l_size = List.length l in
  match l_size with
  |3 -> listCartes d t
  |4 ->
```

note that donne is a type defined like this `type donne = card*card`
and table is defined like this `type table = card*card*card*card*card`

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: How to do complete the function for the 4 and 5 cases

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is a typical example of problem in which considering a more general case makes it easier. Consider the problem of finding all combinaisons of `n` cards in a hand of `l` cards.

---

For the sake of simplicity, I'll consider that `card`s are just generic `'a`. Also, I won't make any difference between the hand and the table, I just consider both as a single list. Separating both could lead to better solutions, but make it less simple to understand :-)

---

So, you'll have a function `comb n l` which returns a list of all the combinations of `n` elements in the list `l` (hence `comb` returns a `'a list list`). Let's do it recursively:

First, if `n` is greater than the length of `l`, just give up:

```
exception NotEnoughElement of int*int
let rec comb n l = 
let length_l = List.length l in
if n > length_l
  raise (NotEnoughElement (n, length_l))
else
```

Now we are sure that `n` is suitable, there are 3 cases to consider depending on `n`: if `n = 0`, then returns an empty list

```
match n with
| 0 -> []
```

if `n` is the size of the list, then there is no choice: the only suitable sublist is... the list itself (this is similar in your case when you have `card`s on the table). Notice that we return a list containing `l` to fulfill our agreement that `comb` returns a list of all sublist.

```
| _ when n == length_l -> [l]
```

finally, if `n` is smaller than the length of `l`, we have a choice to make: either we take the head of `l`, either we don't.

```
| _ ->
```

If we take the head of `l`, then we have to search for combination of `n-1` elements in the tail of `l`, and we append the head of `l` to all those subcombinations. To do the appending, take this function

```
  let app_head sublist = (List.hd l) :: sublist in
```

How to take the combination of `n-1` elements in the tail of `l` ? Well, we have aggrement saying that `comb n l` returns the list of all combination of size `n` in `l`, so we can use this "contract":

```
  let sublists = comb (n-1) (List.tl l) in
```

Now, let's do the appending, the List module provides a `map` function which applies a function to all elements of the list, we can use our `app_head` function:

```
  let combination_head_taken = List.map app_head sublists in
```

Now, if we don't take the head, then we still have to search for `n` elements in the tail of `l`. Once again, we use our aggrement on `comb`:

```
  let combination_head_not_taken = comb (n-1) (List.tl l) in
```

And then, just concatenate combinations generated in the two subcases:

```
  combination_head_taken @ combination_head_not_taken
```

You can then play with [utop](https://opam.ocaml.org/blog/about-utop/) (assuming you wrote this function in `comb.ml`):

```
$ utop
# #use "comb.ml";;
# let hand = [1;2;3;4;5];;
# comb 3 hand;;
- : int list list = [[2; 3; 4; 5]; [1; 3; 4; 5]; [1; 2; 4; 5]; [1; 2; 3; 5]]
```